# Image has extra space at the top

Tags: html, css

I have an image on my website and there is about 50px of extra white space at the top. I have tried padding none and margin none, display block but none of them work. [Here is a working jsfiddle of it.](https://jsfiddle.net/s77zooyd/4/)
Here's my HTML

```css
     h1 {
     font-size: 100px;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     opacity: none;
     font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
      }

    p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    }

      .rotate {
       float: left;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) 2s;
      transform: rotate(180deg) 2s;
      transition: all 2s ease;
      transition-delay: 0.4s;
        }

      .rotate:hover {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          -ms-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
         }

    .container {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    position: static;
    z-index: 150;
     margin-bottom: -80px;
      }
 
    .container a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
        transition: background 1s;
       }

    .dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
     }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 40px 70px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        transition: background 1s;
      }

       .container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: lightgreen;
        }

     .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
     }

    .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
      }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
     }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
         }
```

```html
     <body>
      <div class="active">
      <div id="background">
     <div class="opacity">
     <div class="container">
     <div class="rotate">
     <img class="chiz" src="kkk.png" alt="Vortex Games">
    </div>
       <a href="index.html">Home</a>
       <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
       <a href="games.html">Games</a>
       <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" 
       onclick="window.location.href='store.html'">Store</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="wall.html">Powerups</a>
        <a href="store.html">Coins</a>
      </div>
      </div>
       </div>
      </div>
       <p class="title">
       We're a top-of-the-line high tech <br>game company
      <br>
      <span style="color:white;font-size:20px;padding:none;display:inline-
       block;">
      <span style="color:red;font-size:100px;padding-top:none;">
      &ndash;<br></span>Driven by passion. Always at our best.</span>
    </p>
     <!--the background div-->
      </div>
 
      <div class="creative">
     <img src="cree.jpg" align="abstop">
      </div>
CSS
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A **minimal** demo is enough...not the whole page. Try trimming down your code to **just enough** to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: thanks sorry i'm still new here

Comment: As i can see you have an answer to your question, please set your question as answered. that will save me and a lot of people time in the future...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `*{margin:0;padding: 0;}` this in your css. Because its not only about your image property. You have more element which has some default css property, which is and can affect your html. * make a universal tag

```css
*{
    margin:0;padding: 0;
}
.creative {
    padding-top: none;  
}
img {
    display: block;   
}

body {
    /*body:0;*/
}

#background {
  background: url('https://sellorelse.ogilvy.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/creativity_technology.png');
  background-position:center top;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: none;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}

.rotate {
  float: left;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) 2s;
  transform: rotate(180deg) 2s;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.rotate:hover {
          -webkit-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          -ms-transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
          transform: rotateZ(-360deg);
}

.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    position: static;
  z-index: 150;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}

.container a {
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
        transition: background 1s;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 20px;
    border: none;
    outline: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 40px 70px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
        transition: background 1s;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="active">
  <div id="background">
  <div class="opacity">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="rotate">
  <img class="chiz" src="kkk.png" alt="Vortex Games">
</div>
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
  <a href="FAQ.html">FAQ</a>
  <a href="games.html">Games</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="window.location.href='store.html'">Store</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="wall.html">Powerups</a>
        <a href="store.html">Coins</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<p class="title">
  We're a top-of-the-line high tech <br>game company
<br>
  <span style="color:white;font-size:20px;padding:none;display:inline-block;">
      <span style="color:red;font-size:100px;padding-top:none;">
      &ndash;<br></span>Driven by passion. Always at our best.</span>
    </p>
<!--the background div-->
</div>

<div class="creative">
<img src="http://drwillsparks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/creativity.jpg" align="abstop">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because of some browser preset margin on the p element. You can remove it with this:

```
p.title {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default html page has margin values. Add this to avoid those spaces

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```